# DEM terrain model tool: Band data type Byte not supported in GMT

Tags: qgis, hillshade

I am trying to create a hillshade. I am using the DEM terrain model tool, choosing the right input file and write output, but keep getting this error message "ERROR 1: Band data type Byte not supported in GMT, giving up.". What does it mean? Is there a plug-in that I have missed to install or am I writing something wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I've deleted the second question, please post it in a separate thread

Comment: What file type have you chosen for output? Maybe include a screenshot of the tool's dialogue in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from the error you’re attempting to write out a GMT-compatible netCDF. According to the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html) (emphasis mine)

> Newly created files (with a type of GMT) will always have units of "meters" for x, y and z but the x_range, y_range and z_range should be correct. 
>   **Note that netCDF does not have an unsigned byte data type, so 8bit rasters will generally need to be converted to Int16 for export to GMT**.

That suggests you need to use the -ot option with something like Int16.

Comment: Thanks! The problem could be solved by manually editing "-of GMT" in the text area in the dialog box to "-of GTiff"